# UI element checks its state before observes subscribes

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I have a problem with updating refresh button state in my Android app. Inside my interactor I have a pair of subjects to control state of my refresh button.

```
class PageInteractor {
    private var isRefreshActionEnabled = false
    private val refreshStatePublisher by lazy {
        BehaviorSubject.create<Boolean>().apply {
            onNext(false)
        }
    }
    private var refreshActionPublisher: PublishSubject<Unit>? = null

    fun observeRefreshButtonState(): Observable<Boolean> {
        return refreshStatePublisher
    }

    fun observeRefreshAction(): Observable<Unit> {
        if (refreshActionPublisher?.hasComplete() == false && refreshActionPublisher?.hasObservers() == true) {
            refreshActionPublisher?.onComplete()
        }

        return PublishSubject.create<Unit>()
            .also {
                refreshActionPublisher = it
                updateRefreshButtonState()
            }
            .doOnDispose {
                updateRefreshButtonState()
            }
    }

    fun setRefreshActionEnabled(value: Boolean) {
        if (isRefreshActionEnabled != value) {
            isRefreshActionEnabled = value
            updateRefreshButtonState()
        }
    }

    fun onRefreshAction() {
        refreshActionPublisher?.onNext(Unit)
    }

    private fun updateRefreshButtonState() {
        refreshStatePublisher.onNext(refreshActionPublisher?.hasComplete() == false
            && refreshActionPublisher?.hasObservers() == true)
    }
}
```

I use this interactor in my presenter, it's a Moxy presenter.

```
class PagePresenter(
        private val pageInteractor: PageInteractor
) : MvpPresenter<PageView> {
    override fun onFirstViewAttach() {
        super.onFirstViewAttach()

        pageInteractor
            .observeRefreshButtonState()
            .subscribe { isEnabled ->
                viewState.setRefreshButtonEnabled(isEnabled)
            }
            .addTo(disposable)
    }

    fun onRefreshButtonClicked() {
        pageInteractor.onRefreshAction()
    }
}
```

My problem is that refresh button is disabled when I open the page. I did some debug and it seems that the source of the problem in method `observeRefreshAction`. This method creates `PublishSubject`, when sets `refreshActionPublisher` and right after that it calls method `updateRefreshButtonState`. This method checks if `PublishSubject` has any subscribers by calling `hasObservers` and result almost always false. It happens because `PublishSubject` is not yet returned to presenter, where I can subscribe on it.

Is there any ways to fix this problem? I have tried to move `updateRefreshButtonState` to  `doOnSubscribe`, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to understand the problem and I wrote some piece of code and added some comments.
So you don't need extra Publish Subject to invoke action, you can just call `onRefreshAction()` and change current state of refreshButtonState.

```
import io.reactivex.Observable
import io.reactivex.subjects.BehaviorSubject
import kotlin.random.Random

class PageInteractor {

    // Initial value is false and after subscription, subscriber will receive that value
    private val refreshButtonState = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(false)

    fun observeRefreshButtonState(): Observable<Boolean> = refreshButtonState.distinctUntilChanged()

    // Invoke refresh action
    fun onRefreshAction() {
        // Change state or toggle state or something else
        // Currently generate random next state
        val nextAction = Random.nextBoolean()
        refreshButtonState.onNext(nextAction)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is possible solution. We just decided to remove `hasComplete` and `hasObservers` checks.